# How to use JavaScript to complete the copy function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to the program!
I want to implement a function, click the button to copy the URL in the onclick to the clipboard for the user to paste it elsewhere, but I don't know how to implement this requirement, I really need everyone's help ,thank you all.

```js
  function copyJoblink(joblink){
        let joblink = "https://chickpt.com.tw/dl?tp=4&um=1&ti={{$formatted_job['id']}}&e=share_job"
        window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(joblink);
        document.execCommand('copy')
    }
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;"  class="job_info_share_paperlink" onclick="copyJoblink('https://chickpt.com.tw/dl?tp=4&um=1&ti={{$formatted_job['id']}}&e=share_job')">copy</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault), you can use the href of your link because default action should not be taken as it normally would be.

Then you will need to use [clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API) and [clipboard.writeText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText) to make it work.

```js
function clipboardCopy(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(event.target.getAttribute('href')).then(() => {
      console.log('clipboard saved url :' + event.target.getAttribute('href'));
    }, () => {
      console.log('clipboard saved url : failed...');
    });
}
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://chickpt.com.tw/dl?tp=4&um=1&ti={{$formatted_job['id']}}&e=share_job"  class="job_info_share_paperlink" onclick="clipboardCopy(event)">copy</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function copyJoblink(jobLink) {
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(jobLink);

  /* Alert the copied text */
  alert("Copied the text: " + jobLink);
}
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:;"  class="job_info_share_paperlink" onclick="copyJoblink('https://chickpt.com.tw/dl?tp=4&um=1&ti={{$formatted_job[\'id\']}}&e=share_job')">copy</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it Like below Tested on Chrome and Microsoft Edge and it is working fine:

```js
function copyJoblink(joblink) {                
  const input = document.createElement('input');
  input.value = joblink;
  document.body.appendChild(input);
  input.focus();
  input.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  
  document.body.removeChild(input);

  alert('Link Copied: ' + joblink);
}
```

```css
a {
  display: block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  line-height: 60px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="job_info_share_paperlink" onclick="copyJoblink('https://chickpt.com.tw/dl?tp=4&um=1&ti={{$formatted_job[\'id\']}}&e=share_job')">copy</a>
```